# Put duplicate array values in to subarray

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

I have an array that is created from a MYSQL query that may have duplicate values, like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => title1
    [1] => title2
    [2] => title2
    [3] => title3
    [4] => title4
    [5] => title5
    [6] => title6
    [7] => title6
    [8] => title6
)
```

I don't want to remove those values so `array_unique()` is not helpful here. Instead I want to group the duplicate values in subarrays so that the new array becomes:

```
Array
(
    [0] => title1
    [dupe1] => Array
        (
            [0] => title2
            [1] => title2
        )

    [1] => title3
    [2] => title4
    [3] => title5
    [dupe2] => Array
        (
            [0] => title6
            [1] => title6
            [2] => title6
        )
)
```

**EDIT**: I tried the following:

```
$clean = array_unique( $array );
$dupes = array_diff($array, array_diff($array, array_diff_assoc($array, $clean)));

foreach ($dupes as $k => $v)
{
    if (in_array($v, $clean))
    {
        $key = array_search($v, $clean);
        unset($clean[$key]);
    }

    $clean[$v]['dupe'][] = $v;
}


dumpArray(array_values($clean));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => title1
    [1] => title3
    [2] => title4
    [3] => title5
    [4] => Array
        (
            [dupe] => Array
                (
                    [0] => title2
                    [1] => title2
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [dupe] => Array
                (
                    [0] => title6
                    [1] => title6
                    [2] => title6
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Yes, and what have you tried already?

Comment: @kingkero - Sorry, I've added my latest (messy) attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to keep the (original) order, you can either work by using [`array_splice`](http://www.php.net/array_splice) and a method similar to your current, or construct `$clean` new altogether - like the following (see it work [here](http://3v4l.org/A7OgZ)):

```
sort($array);
$unique_length = count( array_unique($array) );
$total_dupes = 0;

$clean = array();

for ($i=0; $i<$unique_length; $i++) {
    $current = array_shift($array);
    if ($current === NULL)//already have all elements
        break;

    $found = 1;
    while (($key = array_search($current, $array)) !== FALSE) {//search for dupes
        $found++;
        unset($array[$key]);
    }

    if ($found == 1)
        array_push($clean, $current);
    else {
        $dupes = array();
        for ($i=0; $i<$found; $i++)
            $dupes[] = $current;
        $total_dupes++;
        $clean['dupe'.$total_dupes] = $dupes;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So here's a way you can do it.. Create a HashMap with the titles as the key and and the index in the original array as the values. This would give you the duplicates grouped together.